# Increase number of concurrent processing in WEKA's Apriori

Tags: weka, data-mining, pentaho, apriori

I am currently using Apriori algorithm in one of our project using WEKA. Is it possible to set multi concurrent process when using this algorithm? If so, how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bottleneck with Apriori shouldn't be the CPU ever.
In the end, it is just counting, which is not very CPU intensive.

It's bottlenecks are supposedly IO and memory.

Why don't try using another algorithm? Depending on your data, Eclat or FPgrowth may be substantially faster.

Comment: Hi Anony-Mousse, I finally use FPGrowth. Btw, is it possible to set the minimum number of items occurrence in itemsets?

Comment: Depends on your implementation I guess. I don't use Weka much anymore.